# How do you remove un-named columns with a vector?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a messy input file with lots of completely blank columns, and I'm trying to remove them like this (all the empty columns are un-named so R assigns V1, V2, etc.):

`df1[,-grep("V\\d+", colnames(df1))]`

However, the above line just returns the vector of all the empty columns (-1, -2, -3, -7, -10...), and doesn't actually remove each column the way df1[, -c(1, 2, 3, 7, 10) would.

Do I need to pass the vector differently?

Sample data (sanitized), was stored as `data.table` converted for `dput()`:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `Employee Name` = c("", "Bob", "", "Bob", "Bob"), V4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Question 1` = c("", 
"--", "", "Yes", ""), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V8 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `Question 2` = c("", "No", "", "Yes", ""), V10 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), V11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Question 3` = c("", 
"--", "", "Yes", ""), V13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V14 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `Question 4` = c("", "--", "", "Yes", ""), V16 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), V17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V18 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V19 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V20 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `Question 5` = c("", "--", "", "Yes", ""), V22 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), V23 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V24 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V25 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Question 6` = c("", 
"--", "", "Yes", ""), V27 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V28 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), V29 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V30 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V31 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"Employee Name", "V4", "V5", "Question 1", "V7", "V8", "Question 2", 
"V10", "V11", "Question 3", "V13", "V14", "Question 4", "V16", 
"V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "Question 5", "V22", "V23", "V24", 
"V25", "Question 6", "V27", "V28", "V29", "V30", "V31"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `df1[, -c(grep("V\\d+", colnames(df1)))]` or `df1[, -c(grep("V\\d+", colnames(df1), value = TRUE))]`?

Comment: @Jaap that throws an `invalid argument to unary operator` error

Comment: @Jaap and to clarify post your edit, `value = TRUE` throws the above error, adding the `-c` wrapper just returns the vector of column indices

Comment: Your code should work, maybe adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) would help clarify your problem.

Comment: @Jaap just added a sample data set

Comment: add `with = FALSE`: `df1[,-grep("V\\d+", colnames(df1)), with = FALSE]`

Comment: @Jaap bingo, thank you

Comment: You can make `class = c("data.table", "data.frame")` to have the `dput` give a data table.

Comment: To be clear, the example works fine with the base R data.frame sample data. If you're using data.table, you need to **a.** show it in your example, **b.** tag it, and **c.** to solve your problem use its syntax, which differs for `[`, as Jaap alluded to above.

Answer (score 1):

The comments point out how to do the regex using `grep` to select the columns, but since you're using `data.table` you can also delete the V## columns by reference.

`dat[, grep("V\\d+", colnames(dat)) := NULL]`

```
   Employee Name Question 1 Question 2 Question 3 Question 4 Question 5 Question 6
1:                                                                                
2:           Bob         --         No         --         --         --         --
3:                                                                                
4:           Bob        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes        Yes
5:           Bob
```